# how to add current date to a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to minify javascript. so i write a batch file. so in output i want that file name with current date.this is my code

```
ECHO OFF PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier set Date=%date ajaxmin PandaStream.js jquery-1.7.2.min.js jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js iscroll.js jquery.custom-scrollbar.js backstretch.min.js overlay.js jquery.hightlight.3.js jquery.dataTables.1.8.2.min.js jquery.poshytip.min.js timeentry.js JQuery.Cookie.js autoresize-1.04.js prettycheckboxes.js tiptip.js jquery.touchSwipe-1.2.5.js jquery.minicolors.min.js jeditable.js chosen.jquery.js jquery.imagesloaded.js JQuery.textareaCounter.plugin.js nicedit.js jquery.progressbar.min.js jquery.DefaultText.js jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.js jquery.colorbox.js jquery.datepick.js jquery.Jcrop.js jquery-datatables-editable.js DeviceDetect.js jquery.cropzoom.js lb.js ../plupload/js/plupload.full.js ../plupload/js/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js common.js hotkeys.js profilemenu.js cssdropdowns.js LB/timelineEventMedia.js vault.js Datevalidation.js Socialmedia.js GuidedTour.js Sharing.js AddFamilyMember.js Uploads.js events.js EventHtmlTemplates.js -out Mini/minScript.* %DEST%\*.js -clobber
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the current date in a batch file, the variable `%date%` has the current date:

```
echo %date%
25/05/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it to variable and then create the file

```
set currdate=%date:/=%
copy filename.txt file-%currdate%.txt
```

Or

```
set backupFilename=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
```

Comment: No its not working..if i write like this then it did not create that file..please check my code...according to that please give me some suggestion.

Comment: @user3095273:Please aceept the answers that helps you.

Comment: now i have another problem.i want time separated by hyphen from date. i tried %TIME:~3,2% but it returns only minute..but i want hour,minute and sec.